# Oracle- Join with not equal condition

Tags: oracle, join

I want to join a select in select in select etc. with a table where I don't have to find the customer_no from selects result in the table.
Also, for optimization and reduction execution time how should I wrote the script?
    ex.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_no,
                str_data_expirare_1,
                data_expirare_buletin_1,
                str_data_expirare_2,
                data_expirare_buletin_2
  FROM (SELECT customer_no,
               str_data_expirare_1,
               data_expirare_buletin_1,
               str_data_expirare_2,
               data_expirare_buletin_2
          FROM (SELECT customer_no,
                       str_data_expirare_1,
                       normalize_date (str_data_expirare_trim_1)
                           AS data_expirare_buletin_1,
                       str_data_expirare_2,
                       normalize_date (str_data_expirare_trim_2)
                           AS data_expirare_buletin_2
                  FROM (SELECT customer_no,
                               str_data_expirare_1,
                               REGEXP_REPLACE (str_data_expirare_1,
                                               '[[:punct:]]',
                                               '')
                                   AS str_data_expirare_trim_1,
                               str_data_expirare_2,
                               REGEXP_REPLACE (str_data_expirare_2,
                                               '[[:punct:]]',
                                               '')
                                   AS str_data_expirare_trim_2
                          FROM (SELECT Q1.customer_no,
                                       Q1.set_act_id_1,
                                       NVL (SUBSTR (set_act_id_1,
                                                      INSTR (set_act_id_1,
                                                             '+',
                                                             1,
                                                             5)
                                                    + 1,
                                                    LENGTH (set_act_id_1)),
                                            'NULL')
                                           AS str_data_expirare_1,
                                       Q1.set_act_id_2,
                                       NVL (SUBSTR (set_act_id_2,
                                                      INSTR (set_act_id_2,
                                                             '+',
                                                             1,
                                                             5)
                                                    + 1,
                                                    LENGTH (set_act_id_2)),
                                            'NULL')
                                           AS str_data_expirare_2
                                  FROM STAGE_CORE.IFLEX_CUSTOMERS Q1
                                 WHERE Q1.set_act_id_1 IS NOT NULL/*AND Q1.PERS_LAST_NAME LIKE 'LACAN'*/
                                                                  )))
         WHERE     str_data_expirare_1 <> 'NULL'
               AND data_expirare_buletin_1 - SYSDATE < 0
               AND (   data_expirare_buletin_2 =
                           TO_DATE ('30-DEC-99', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                    OR data_expirare_buletin_2 < SYSDATE)) T1
JOIN STAGE_CORE.IFLEX_CUSTOMERS_REPRES T2
           ON T1.CUSTOMER_NO = T2.representative
       JOIN STAGE_CORE.VW_IFLEX_ACCOUNTS_IBAN t3
           ON t3.Cust_key <> T2.representative
 WHERE T2.relationship <> 'EXTERN' AND T2.REPRESENTATIVE <> T2.REF_NO
```

The query has to find all people with identity card expired which are authorized on someone else account (from a bank) and doesn't have any account opened.

- STAGE_CORE.IFLEX_CUSTOMERS_REPRES - the table with all accounts and
  authoried on accounts
- JOIN STAGE_CORE.VW_IFLEX_ACCOUNTS_IBAN - the table with all accounts
  and details
- STAGE_CORE.IFLEX_CUSTOMERS - the table with all customers

#### Sample data:

- VW_IFLEX_ACCOUNTS_IBAN

  ```
  UNIT_ID CUST_KEY ACCOUNT_NO         IBAN                AC_OPEN_DATE ACC_ISOPEN
    51    875497  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   29/02/2016   O
    51    875497  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   08/03/2016   C
    51    875497  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   01/03/2016   O
   751    875497  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   12/08/2011   C
   466    875497  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   22/01/2013   O
  ```
- IFLEX_CUSTOMERS_REPRES

  ```
  REF_NO CATEGORY TITULAR REPRESENTATIVE RELATIONSHIP
  875497     C     875497    535555      UNICA
  875497     C     875497    565796      UNICA
  875497     C     875497    875497      PRIMARY-MEANS I AM AUTHORIZED ON MY ACCOUNT
  875497     C     875497    875497      UNICA-MEANS I AM AUTHORIZED ON MY ACCOUNT
  875497     C     875497    0O00000     EXTERN -- MEANS EVERYONE CAN PUT MONEY ON MY ACCOUNT
  ```
- IFLEX_CUSTOMERS

  ```
  CUSTOMER_NO LEGACY_CUSTOMER_NUMBER_KEY UNIT_ID CUST_CATEGORY CUST_CLASSIFICATION CUST_TYPE KYC_CUST_TYPE CIF_SINCE FISCAL_ID    FULL_NAME         FISCAL_RESIDENCE_COUNTRY NIF_EXPIRED_DATE NIF                   SET_ACT_ID_1               SET_ACT_ID_2
  875497      875497                     xxx     RETAIL         80                    I              R     254911    2548614654 LACAN MARIA ADRIANA              RO              01/03/2016   CI+XX+8646844+SPCLEP SIMM+01-Oct-2015+06-Dec-2022 +FN+FN+++
  ```

OUTPUT:

```
CUSTOMER_NO STR_DATA_EXPIRARE_1 DATA_EXPIRARE_BULETIN_1 STR_DATA_EXPIRARE_2 DATA_EXPIRARE_BULETIN_2
535555     29-Apr-16           29-Apr-16               NULL                30-Dec-99
0Jxx1ds0    09-Sep-16           09-Sep-16               NULL                30-Dec-99
2xx8ds      24-Mar-16           24-Mar-16               NULL                30-Dec-99
2756719     20-Feb-17           20-Feb-17               NULL                30-Dec-99
```

this customers must not have any account to this bank

Comment: It would be helpful it you would provide sample data for each table, and the expected outcome for that data. Also your query seems to have a lot of logic which you do not explain. Either take it out, or -- if it is relevant to the question -- explain it: why `<> 'EXTERN'`, `'30-DEC-99'`, `INSTR(... '+'...)`, ... etc.

Comment: I can't show details because of the internal politics. But,

Comment: Not real data, but test data, sample data.

Comment: done, maybe you can put it into excel...

Comment: You have data in the output that appears nowhere in your input, so it gives no clue about the logic. In the meanwhile I formatted your data so it appears well in the question. Please, if you update, take into account this way of formatting.

Comment: let's say you are authorized on my accounts. The output is your account with your data of your identity card (which is expired) and also you don't have any accounts opened on this bank. So this is the output. You are the REPRESENTATIVE on one of my accounts (CUSTOMERS_REPRES table), you also apperar in the CUSTOMERS table, but not in the ACCOUNTS_IBAN table

Comment: Obviously this code is refers to question on cleansing dates. But all that stuff is *irrelevant to this question*. The regex and stuff makes it harder to understand your problem and so less likely people will try to help. If you want people to spend their time helping you, you should invest some of your time framing a decent question. That means trimming your actual code to something simple which clearly demonstrates the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be frank I'm going to ignore that sprawling chunk of code and answer the question using the focused, reproducible test case you should have posted :)

What you need is an anti-join. Use the `left join` syntax to connect Customers with Accounts then filter results where the Account key is null. This gives you Customers without Accounts. But `inner join` on Customers and Representatives to ensure that the set of Customers is restricted to those who are also Representatives.

```
select c.customer_no
       , c.expired_date
from customers c
     inner join customers_repres cr
          on cr.representative_id =  c.customer_no
     left outer join accounts_iban ai
          on ai.cust_key =  c.customer_no
where c.expired_date is not null -- ?? indicates expired ID ??
and ai.cust_key is null
```

Comment: My query works very well, but my question was how to optimize the query ? it's ok for a small database, but on large ones, like i'm working, for a bank, it's not good at all. should I make the joins inside the 'first select'? And excuse me, I'm just a beginner, like very beginner, so don't judge me. And I'm beginner too on this site.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
select * from STAGE_CORE.IFLEX_CUSTOMERS c
join
STAGE_CORE.IFLEX_CUSTOMERS_REPRES cr
on c.CUSTOMER_NO=cr.REPRESENTATIVE
left join STAGE_CORE.VW_IFLEX_ACCOUNTS_IBAN a
on a.cust_key=cr.REPRESENTATIVE
where cr.RELATIONSHIP<>'PRIMARY'
and a.CUST_KEY is not null
```